# Prevent download of an mp3 in wordpress but let it be played via WP-Plugin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, download, mp3

I'm uploading some self composed music to my website which shall be played with an Audio-Plugin. I stumbled over the opportunity to catch the direct links from the HTML source code. Now i tried to protect the files with an htaccess file in that Folder (i found that solution in another Forum)

```
Options -Indexes
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
```

But with this htaccess file the Plugin isn't able to Play the Music. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You simply can't

Answer (score 0):

As even a totally unskilled user can easily download any media file using the Media tab of the Firefox Page Info Tool, you cannot prevent a user from downloading your media file if you send as it as a media file. However, if you look for a YouTube video in the Media tab you will not find anything. This is because the video is not sent as a media file but as a MPEG-DASH stream. If you really want to prevent your users from easily downloading your media file you cannot send it as a raw media file. You need to use another representation such as MPEG-DASH.

[Note: I deleted my previous answer because the above basically invalidates that answer.]